# Modify another app's SQLite database in Android 6.0+ using root access

Tags: android, sqlite, root, selinux

I have an app in Android that needs to modify the private databases of other apps using root. The current method works on all devices up to and including Lollypop, but seems to fail on Marshmallow devices due to SELinux.

To modify databases, the app does the following:

- From root:

  - Copy target database to my app's folder preserving permissions and ownership (cp -p)
  - Change permissions (chmod 777)
- From app, use SQLiteDatabase class to open database and execute queries
- From root

  - Move back database and restore permissions

However, on Marshmallow, attempting to open the copied database with SQLiteDatabase fails and yields the follow AVC denial:

```
avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/<my app package>/cache/<database>.db" dev="dm-0" ino=509488 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

The only thing I've tried is running `chcon u:r:untrusted_app:s0` on the file as root, but it says permission denied.

Additionally, from what I've read here: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/, it appears that SELinux was set to enforcing mode in the 5.0 release, so how come this is only an issue now on 6.0 but wasn't on 5.0?

Answer (score 2):

I have just completed something like this for one of my apps so it works on Android 7 on a Pixel device.

Like you, I copy the original database files to my app's location. Then I not only chmod them but I also chown/chgrp them to my app's uid. Finally, I chcon the database files to the context found for them in their original location. I am then able to access and manipulate them via SqliteDatabase classes in my app.

Once I am finished, I move the database files back to their original location, chown/chgrp them back to the owning app's uid, and restorecon them.

This is a giant pain. But it seems to work in my limited testing so far. But beware that in later versions of Android the toolbox commands seem to have been replaced with toybox commands and this really impacts the chown/chgrp. Toolbox versions allow changing of owner and group in the same command. Toybox does not so you must issue both chown and chgrp commands.

There may be other command changes as well. for example, on the Pixel, the grep command is now a stand-alone binary and NOT a part of toolbox or toybox.

Comment: Ugh. chcon was what i was missing. Be sure to use ls -Z on the original file, what I needed was "chcon u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 <filename>".

Answer (score 0):

you can turn off the enforcing mode and move to permissive mode using `adb shell su 0 setenforce 0` through code.

In permissive mode you are allowed do to do whatever you would do on normal phone without SELinux.

Once the enforcing mode is turned off you can do whatever you were doing before.

Comment: Many phones don't allow you to use setenforce (see answer on https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54577/how-can-i-change-selinux-from-enforcing-to-permissive-on-samsung-galaxy-note-3)

Comment: @user2443357 since yours is rooted device you should be able to do it, no need to worry.

Comment: No, I've tried it on two rooted devices (one 5.0 and one 6.0) and it didn't work on either. You need a different kernel in addition to root access. From the answer I linked to: "Apparently, since AOS >4.4, Google started using a permanent enforcing mode which actually enforces the SELinux policy. These phones have disabled the Permissive option through the DCONFIG_ALWAYS_ENFORCE=true kernel config flag in their Kernels. You need to flash an insecure Kernel (e.g. CF_Root) or a brand new kernel where this flag has been disabled."

Comment: I guess you need to edit the domain for ur app in *.te files and push it to the device..i don't remember exactly but those are the files where selinux maintains various access configuration

Comment: So is there no way to do this using only a rooted shell?

Comment: There must be! Plenty of tools in Play Store that can do it.